# Can't start MemoryAnalyzer-1.15.0.20231206-win32.win32.x86_64

Tags: mat, memoryanalyzer

I always fail to use MemoryAnalyzer-1.15.0.20231206-win32.win32.x86_64.

Java Virtual Machine lancher
Error: Could not create the java virtual machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

But I have installed java 8:
U:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_401"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode, sharing)

And i have added the it into system env PATH:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin

I want to enable MemoryAnalyzer